# Find the correct answer

Tags: integers

Let $n\geq 3$ be an integer. Then the statement
$(n!)^{1/n}\leq\frac{n+1}{2}$ is

a) true for every $n\geq 3$,

b) true if and only if $n\geq 5$,

c) not true for $n\geq 10$,

d) true for even integers $n\geq 6$, not true for odd $n\geq 5$.

Please help me to solve this in general method without any trial and hit method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\dfrac{r+n-r}2\ge\sqrt{r(n-r)}$$ Set $r=1,2\cdots\n-1,n$

Answer (score 3):

by AM-GM we have $$\sqrt[n]{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n}\le\frac{1+2+3+...+n}{n}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n}=\frac{n+1}{2}$$